# I am getting lots of errors in my project after updating Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-adt

I updated my Eclipse with sdkmanager but all of my projects won't run, and the sdkmanager won't open for restore. Please help. Errors are:

```
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] Versions found are:
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] Path: D:\Android Tools\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects]   Length: 621451
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects]   SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] Path: D:\Android Tools\Project\actionbarprojects\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects]   Length: 556198
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects]   SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2014-05-27 15:00:56 - actionbarprojects] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Unable to access jarfile lib\archquery.jar
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2014-05-27 15:00:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Access is denied.
```

Comment: please update your eclipse tools also (ADT Bundle tools) from Help->check for updates.. then it works

Comment: Here i have error too :Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/content.xml
download.eclipse.org
Unknown Host: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml
dl-ssl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2/content.xml
download.eclipse.org

Comment: none of your links work, 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list

You have different versions of the  `android-support-v4.jar`. Update your Support library from android sdk manager.

Copy android-support-v4.jar from

```
adt-bundle/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-supportv4.jar
```

and add it to the build path of both AppCompat and your Android project.

You can add it to projects libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** You need to delete `android-support-v4.jar` from library and project.

**Step 2:**  Copy `android-support-v4.jar` from library project and paste in your project  wihin `libs` folder

**Step 3 :** Now clean your project.

**You can also update  your eclipse tools (ADT Bundle tools)** .